# authenticated user not detected on non-API routes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

Passport Version
11.08

Laravel Version
10

PHP Version
8.1.4

Database Driver & Version
mysql 8

I'm working on a Laravel and Vue.js project. The frontend is a single-page application (SPA) accessible through panel.foo.com, while the login route is api.foo.com/login and belongs to the api middleware group. A token is received and stored in the SPA when a user successfully logs in. On the main page with the URL foo.com, which is a non-SPA just blade in the web middleware group, the login user is not detected and no laravel_token cookie is created.

I added the CreateFreshApiToken::class middleware to the web middleware group, but it did not solve the problem. In the controller of the main page, I have used

dd(auth()->check(),auth('api')->check())

and both return false.

I have checked the middleware group, and CreateFreshApiToken::class exists in the web middleware group. However, when using the panel APIs, which belong to the api middleware group, the CreateFreshApiToken::class is not executed to create the laravel_token cookie. On the main page, when CreateFreshApiToken::class is executed, $request->user($this->guard) is null. Therefore, the laravel_token cookie is not created.

Here are my auth configuration settings:

session_domain set to .foo.com

```
'defaults' => [
'guard' => 'web',
'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
'web' => [
'driver' => 'session',
'provider' => 'users',
],
'api' => [
'driver' => 'passport',
'provider' => 'users',
],
],
```

And here is my kernel.php file:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
'web' => [
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],

'api' => [
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class . ':api',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
],
];
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'r mixing the api Guard with web.
When you're logged in via the API. It will have the logged in user in the "api" guard. But, this doesn't mean you can access the same user via the web guard.

What you can do is to log the api user in on web as well.
Something like this for web-based auth once you're authenticated via API:

```
$apiAuthenticatedUser = Auth::guard('api')->user();
if ($apiAuthenticatedUser) Auth::Login($apiAuthenticatedUser);
```